# REST API versioning using AWS

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, cloud, versioning

After going trough this [link](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http#i_want_my_api_to_be_versioned) on API versioning, i am trying to adapt the version through the headers and deploy it of AWS, but it looks like AWS does not support any custom verndor specific MIME types([link here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/MIMETypes.html))

Any idea how to achieve the versioning in this scenario where you do not have control over the MIME type...or any insights on how to do API versioning when using AWS?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion for cloud based service is "v1.api.mysite.com". It provides good flexibility. More details and reasoning here - http://timanovsky.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/api-versioning-scheme-for-cloud-rest-services/